# SQL query for most recent messages

Tags: mysql

I am trying to implement a message system quite similar to facebook . The message table is :

```
+--------+----------+--------+-----+----------+
| msg_id | msg_from | msg_to | msg | msg_time |
+--------+----------+--------+-----+----------+
```

Here `msg_from` and `msg_to` contain user ids and the `msg_time` contains the timestamp of the message . A user's user id can appear in both the to and from column and multiple times for another user . How should I write a SQL query which selects the most recent sent message between two users ? (The message can come from either one) 1 to 2 or 2 to 1 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since John Woo clarified that it is not directional, here's my new answer:

```
select *
from msgsList
where (least(msg_from, msg_to), greatest(msg_from, msg_to), msg_time)       
in 
(
    select 
       least(msg_from, msg_to) as x, greatest(msg_from, msg_to) as y, 
       max(msg_time) as msg_time
    from msgsList 
    group by x, y
);
```

Output:

```
| MSG_ID | MSG_FROM | MSG_TO |    MSG |                       MSG_TIME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |        1 |      2 |  hello | January, 23 2010 17:00:00-0800 |
|      5 |        1 |      3 | me too | January, 23 2012 00:15:00-0800 |
|      6 |        3 |      2 |  hello | January, 23 2012 01:12:12-0800 |
```

For this input:

```
create table msgsList
(
  msg_id int,
  msg_from int, 
  msg_to int,
  msg varchar(10),
  msg_time datetime
);

insert into msgslist VALUES

(1, 1, 2, 'hello', '2010-01-23 17:00:00'),      -- shown
(2, 2, 1, 'world', '2010-01-23 16:00:00'),

(3, 3, 1, 'i am alive', '2011-01-23 00:00:00'),
(4, 3, 1, 'really', '2011-01-22 23:15:00'),
(5, 1, 3, 'me too', '2012-01-23 00:15:00'),     -- shown

(6, 3, 2, 'hello', '2012-01-23 01:12:12');      -- shown
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a575/17)

---

If ANSI SQL is your cup of tea, here's the way to do it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a575/19

```
select *
from msgsList z
where exists
(
    select null
    from msgsList
    where 
      least(z.msg_from, z.msg_to) = least(msg_from, msg_to)
      and greatest(z.msg_from, z.msg_to) = greatest(msg_from, msg_to)
    group by least(msg_from, msg_to), greatest(msg_from, msg_to)
    having max(msg_time) = z.msg_time  
) ;
```

Comment: `+1` for using `LEAST` and `GREATEST`

Comment: Works like a Dream !! Thanks a LOT!!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this simple? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50f9f/1

```
set @User1 := 'John';
set @User2 := 'Paul';


select *
from
(
  select *
  from messages 
  where msg_from = @User1 and msg_to = @User2
  order by msg_time desc
  limit 1
) as x
union
select *
from
(
  select *
  from messages 
  where msg_from = @User2 and msg_to = @User1
  order by msg_time desc
  limit 1
) as x
order by msg_time desc
```

Output:

```
| MSG_ID | MSG_FROM | MSG_TO |         MSG |                      MSG_TIME |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      2 |     Paul |   John | Hey Johnny! | August, 20 2012 00:00:00-0700 |
|      1 |     John |   Paul | Hey Paulie! | August, 19 2012 00:00:00-0700 |
```

---

Could be a lot simpler if only MySQL supported windowing function: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e4781/8

```
with recent_message as
(
select *, rank() over(partition by msg_from, msg_to order by msg_time desc) as r
from messages
)
select * 
from recent_message 
where r = 1 
    and 
    (
      (msg_from = 'John' and msg_to = 'Paul') 
      or
      (msg_from = 'Paul' and msg_to = 'John')
    )
order by msg_time desc;
```

Comment: is this sql statement can answer this set of records? [*SQFiddle link*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bd90/1 "click here to redirect")

Comment: Hmm.. I read the OP's requirement as returning the recent conversation between two users only :-) Hence requiring two parameters only

Comment: Seeing your query [*HERE*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50f9f/1), it should only return `msgid = 2` because it is the most recent and the message can either be sent by `John to Paul` or `Paul to John`

Comment: Anyway, I understand what you meant here on your SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bd90/1 I'll think of a solution :-)

Comment: Don't take this as a negative comment but I think the OP needs to get all msgs from the users. I see your point if he needs only two values. What if he wants to retrieve the conversation of many users like the link i provided? honestly, I've been searching snippets how to have results wherein `peter and north` is the same as `north and peter` :D btw, are you pinoy? hehe

Comment: +1 to John . I need only msgid=2 . Also yes , peter and north and north and peter are supposed to be same . Also of course I need multiple users .

Comment: @JohnWoo It now return `msgid=2` only. Here's the result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50f9f/3. Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027792/11432

Comment: @JohnWoo Yes I'm pinoy ツ I see many of your answers are good, you achieve 10k rep in no time, kudos to that!

Comment: @VarunJain I think your problem is now solved. Check Michael's answer @ [*Click HERE*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027792/491243)

Comment: @JohnWoo RE: Take as negative comment. None was taken ツ In fact, I'm challenged by it. You are good on deciphering the OP question's intent/objective. Thanks kabayan! ツ

Answer (score 1):

For any complex query like this, use TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design.  Devise the answer step-by-step, with the size of the steps controlled by your experience and how well you understand the problem.

#### Step 1 — Find the time of the most recent message between the given users

Throughout this, I assume that the user IDs are integers; I'm using the values 1000 and 2000.

```
SELECT MAX(msg_time) AS msg_time
  FROM message
 WHERE ((msg_to = 1000 AND msg_from = 2000) OR
        (msg_to = 2000 AND msg_from = 1000)
       )
```

#### Step 2 — Find the record corresponding to the most recent message

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM message AS m
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(msg_time) AS msg_time
          FROM message
         WHERE ((msg_to = 1000 AND msg_from = 2000) OR
                (msg_to = 2000 AND msg_from = 1000)
               )
       ) AS t
    ON t.msg_time = m.msg_time
 WHERE ((m.msg_to = 1000 AND m.msg_from = 2000) OR
        (m.msg_to = 2000 AND m.msg_from = 1000)
       )
```

If there happen to be two (or more) messages between these characters with the same latest timestamp, then they'll all be selected; there is at present no basis for choosing between the collisions.  If you think that's a problem, you can arrange to find the `MAX(msg_id)` using the query above (as a sub-query):

```
SELECT m2.*
  FROM message AS m2
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(m.msg_id) AS msg_id
          FROM message AS m
          JOIN (SELECT MAX(msg_time) AS msg_time
                  FROM message
                 WHERE ((msg_to = 1000 AND msg_from = 2000) OR
                        (msg_to = 2000 AND msg_from = 1000)
                       )
               ) AS t
            ON t.msg_time = m.msg_time
         WHERE ((m.msg_to = 1000 AND m.msg_from = 2000) OR
                (m.msg_to = 2000 AND m.msg_from = 1000)
               )
       ) AS i
    ON i.msg_id = m2.msg_id
```

**Warning**: *Code not formally tested with any DBMS.*

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought, I came up with this:

```
SELECT min_user AS min(msg_from, msg_to), max_user AS max(msg_from, msg_to), 
max(msg_date) FROM msg GROUP BY min_user, max_user
```

I'm still not quite sure how to get the additional data from the message, but I'll give it some thought.

Comment: This will select multipl values for a pair . Pair is unique . It does not matter if the order of the pair is changed.There can be multiple messages . I need the lastest message only .

Comment: Okay, so then you add LIMIT 1

Comment: But that won't give me the other unique pairs . I would get just one pair . A user recieves messages from multiple users . 

I need latest messages from all unique pairs. Pair is not direction dependent .